NodeJS Connecting to CosmosDB fails when creating client from connection string
I have the following code that fails on the line where I instantiate the CosmosClient. There is an option to instantiate a CosmosClient from a connection string. The string is in my environment variables and in the format AccountEndpoint=https://ACCNAME.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=KEY;
This should all work but when I run npm start, the following error displays in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endpoint')
    at new CosmosClient (CosmosClient.js:41:1)
    at App (App.js:6:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14128:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17417:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18713:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23672:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22942:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22865:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22838:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:22330:1)

Any help appreciated!
Using azure active directory credentials is not something that I want to do right now as I'm simply trying to get this working with admin privileges before I actually deploy(this is not live so there's no security risks with this). What should happen is there's no errors and I am able to fetch database data.

This doesn't seem like a Cosmos DB issue if the endpoint setting is undefined. Seems like more of an issue retrieving your environment variable. Have you inspected the connection string in your debugger to confirm whether a value has been read in?

The constructor of the CosmosClient is either:
new CosmosClient({connectionString: "<connection string>"})

or
new CosmosClient({
     endpoint: "<URL HERE>",
     auth: {masterKey: "<KEY HERE>"}
  });

Seems like the object being passed to the constructor is undefined instead of a valid object.

Yep seems like the environment wasn't being loaded so the environment variable returned as null
